# .net json deserializer failing for google api returned json result

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am unable to deserialize the json result I am getting from google api during an API call. The API request is successful, but I can't deserialize it.

**Code for deserialization is as follows :**

```
var datareceived = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

**Please find below the json I am getting from Google api(response object in above code) :**

```
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"distance between the trees","confidence":0.46962094},{"transcript":"Justin prescription that reason"},{"transcript":"Justin Swift accessories"},{"transcript":"justice respiratory"},{"transcript":"Justin syska accessories"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}
```

**Exception Details :**

```
Message = "Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 2, position 0."
```

**RootObject Class :**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    public int result_index { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get both results in response?

`{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"...`

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: Yes. I am getting like this. I think it would work if it has only one result. But I am new to this. Is this a json array? How to deserialize it?

Comment: I have never seen a JSON response like this. Weird.

Comment: If `{"result":[]}` is constant, maybe you can use `SubString` to remove it and proceed?

Comment: Oh. fine. That could be possible. I was looking for some way to deserialize this.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize following method to get JSON in List:

```
public List<string> GetJsonItems(string jsonString)
{
    int bracketCount = 0;
    List<string> jsonItems = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder Json = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in jsonString)
    {
        if (c == '{')
            ++bracketCount;
        else if (c == '}')
            --bracketCount;
        Json.Append(c);

        if (bracketCount == 0 && c != ' ')
        {
            jsonItems.Add(Json.ToString());
            Json = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
    return jsonItems;
}
```

Then utilize it like:

```
List<string> strings = GetJsonItems(response.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty));

if (strings.Length > 1)
{
    List<Rootobject> allResultSet = new List<Rootobject>();
    foreach (var str in strings)
    {
        Rootobject items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(str);
        if (items.result.Length > 0)
        {
            allResultSet.Add(items);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. But this does not seem to be a proper solution. If there are multiple result sets, then I will face the issue. Need not be the first result is always null.

Comment: But it won't work anyway since the result sets are multiple. I am getting something like a json array. I need to deserialze multiple result sets somehow.

Comment: @ViVi Then I think you should share the JSON you are getting.

Comment: @ViVi I have updated my answer, please check if it could be of any help.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But the function `GetJsonItems()` doesn't do what is expected since there are multiple `{` and `}` in the second line and we cannot make sure that it is the beginning and end of a json object.

Comment: @ViVi did you try it? I have tested it using the multiple JSONs you provided and it works fine.

Comment: I tried. But it returns 4 lines instead of 2. with 2 extra lines with value : `\n`

Comment: @ViVi I have updated my answer. Please go through it and let me know if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

you just can't parse this JSON as it is because `}` symbolize the end of JSON

but you can do something like this

```
string json = "{\"result\":[]}\r\n{\"result\":[{\"alternative\":[{\"transcript\":\"distance between the trees\",\"confidence\":0.46962094},{\"transcript\":\"Justin prescription that reason\"},{\"transcript\":\"Justin Swift accessories\"},{\"transcript\":\"justice respiratory\"},{\"transcript\":\"Justin syska accessories\"}],\"final\":true}],\"result_index\":0}";

string trueJson = json.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
try
{
    RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(trueJson);
    rootObject = rootObject;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{      
    throw;
}

public class Alternative
{
    public string transcript { get; set; }
    public double confidence { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Alternative> alternative { get; set; }
    public bool final { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    public int result_index { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that each line of the result contains a separate JSON object. (It's not clear why the API doesn't return an actual JSON array instead.) If this is the case, you can split the response into lines and parse each line separately:

```
string[] lines = response.Split(new char[]{'\r','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var datareceived1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(lines[0]);
```

... and so on.